# how to compare list elements(type string) and string(in request scope) using struts 2 tags

Tags: jsp, struts2, tags, string-comparison, ognl

My List contains("A","B","C","D") elements

```
<s:iterator value="lis">
  <s:property /><br>
</s:iterator>
```

and String str="A";

```
<s:property value="%{#request.str}"/>
```

I want to compare every element of list(lis) with String s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the [IteratorStatus](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/views/jsp/IteratorStatus.html) object:

```
<s:iterator value="lis" status="ctr">
    <s:property /> 
    <s:if test="%{#request.str.equals(lis[#ctr.index])}">
        -> This value from "lis" is equal to the value of "str"
    </s:if>
    <br/>
</s:iterator>
```

With the [**var** parameter](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/iterator.html):

```
<s:iterator value="lis" var="currentValue">
    <s:property /> 
    <s:if test="%{#request.str.equals(#currentValue)}">
        -> This value from "lis" is equal to the value of "str"
    </s:if>
    <br/>
</s:iterator>
```

With the `top` keyword:

```
<s:iterator value="lis">
    <s:property /> 
    <s:if test="%{#request.str.equals(top)}">
        -> This value from "lis" is equal to the value of "str"
    </s:if>
    <br/>
</s:iterator>
```

You may wanna read the short [<kbd>OGNL Language Guide</kbd>](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/language-guide.html) for more details.