# Struts2 JSP s:iterator inside an s:iterator

Tags: jsp, struts2, iterator

I am new to Struts 2 & JSP. The question might be silly; please bear with me, if so. I have the following structure created in my Java program - I have an ArrayList comprising of HashMaps. One sample is as follows:

**[{Name=S S. Peter, Email=xyz@yahoo.com, Type=P/C, Location=New York}, {Name=Tom Hanks, Email=tom.hanks@gmail.com, Type=C/A, Location=null}, {Name=Carl Zeiss, Email=null, Type=C/A, Location=null}]**

Here the List name is ComboMeals and the HashMap name is authors.

I want to display these values in the form of a table. I am using the following construct in JSP:

```
    <s:iterator value="comboMeals">
 <div class="Row" align="left">
     <s:iterator value="authors" var="numbers"> 
        <s:set var="authorTypeKey" value="key" />
            <div class="Cell" align="left">
                <s:if test="%{#authorTypeKey=='Type'}">
                    <p><s:textfield name="selectedTypeTxtBox" value="%{authors.Type}"></s:textfield><br>
                    <s:select list="listOfTypes" name="selectedType" value="%{authors.Type}" onchange="getSelectedType(this)"></s:select><br><br></p>
                </s:if>
                <s:elseif test="%{#authorTypeKey=='Name'}">
                    <p><s:textfield name="selectedNameTxtBox" value="%{authors.Name}"></s:textfield><br>
                    <s:select  list="listOfNames" name="selectedName" value="%{authors.Name}" onchange="getSelectedName(this)"></s:select><br><br></p>
                </s:elseif>
                <s:elseif test="%{#authorTypeKey=='Location'}">
                     <p><s:textfield  name="selectedLocationTxtBox" value="%{authors.Location}"></s:textfield><br>
                    <s:select list="listOfLocations" name="selectedLocation" value="%{authors.Location}" onchange="getSelectedLocation(this)"></s:select><br><br></p>
                </s:elseif>
                <s:elseif test="%{#authorTypeKey=='Email'}">
                     <p><s:textfield name="selectedEmailTxtBox" value="%{authors.Email}"></s:textfield><br>
                    <s:select list="listOfEmails" name="selectedEmail" value="%{authors.Email}" onchange="getSelectedEmail(this)"></s:select><br><br></p>
                </s:elseif>
            </div>
      </s:iterator>
 </div>
```

--Please ignore the JavaScript for onChange event (this is for s:select).

But it is not displaying any values. Could you please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using var, read the values from it, not from the iterable source (without specifying an index): change all your `value="%{authors.Something}"` in your select boxes with `value="%{numbers.Something}"`.

Also read:

1. [All the ways to read an iterated object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19516627/1654265) (index, var, top)
2. [How to deal with nested Collections / Maps in Struts2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15009137/1654265) (by creating wrapping objects)

P.S: for a better help, next time consider posting your java objects and declaration, instead (or in addition to) the content of your objects.