# How to use if test in struts 2 response is an arraylist type and field name is dynamic

Tags: struts2

I'm able to iterate the array list perfectly, but I have to test if dept code (`deptc`) matches with some conditions and do something accordingly:

```
<s:iterator value="deptAttendace" status="stat"> 
    <s:text name="%{'deptAttendace['+#stat.index+'].deptc'}"/> 
</s:iterator>

<s:if test= "%{#deptAttendace['+#stat.index+'].deptc=='804'}">
    <s:text   name="%{'deptAttendace['+#stat.index+'].deptc'}"/> 
    is computer science deptc 
</s:if>
```

I have written above code but this doesn't work.

Comment: <s:iterator value="deptAttendace" status="stat"> 
    <s:if test= "%{#deptAttendace['+#stat.index+'].deptc=='804'}">
    <s:text   name="%{'deptAttendace['+#stat.index+'].deptc'}"/> 
    is computer science deptc 
</s:if>
</s:iterator>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to put the s:if inside the iterator;
2. the concatenation of stat.index is wrong;
3. Remove the `#` in front of deptAttendace.

```xml
<s:iterator value="deptAttendace" status="stat"> 
    <s:text name="deptAttendace[%{#stat.index}].deptc}" /> 

    <s:if test="%{deptAttendace[#stat.index].deptc=='804'}">
        is computer science deptc 
    </s:if>
</s:iterator>
```

There are several ways to access the iterated object, <kbd>[read them here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19516627/1654265)</kbd>.

Comment: yes i am doing the same if test condition iside the iterator but it is not showing any thing even deptc code is 804..........

Comment: <s:if test= "%{#deptAttendace[#stat.index].deptc=='804'}"> /*my specific doubt is with test condition syntax....  is it right or wrong?*/

Comment: Thanks Andrea ........it's working now..i was fighting for hours for this..thank u very much.

Answer (score 0):

try this one,

```
<s:iterator value="deptAttendace" status="stat"> 
 <s:text name="deptAttendace.get(#stat.index).getDeptc()"/> 
</s:iterator>

<s:if test= "deptAttendace.get(#stat.index).getDeptc()=='804'}">
<s:text   name="deptAttendace.get(#stat.index).getDeptc()"/> 
is computer science deptc 
</s:if>
```