# How can I print List<Object[]> with Struts 2?

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist, struts2, ognl

In my java action class I have:

```
List<Object[]> objlistwitharry;
```

How can I display this in JSP with Struts2 ? I've tried :

```xml
<s:iterator value="objlistwitharry" var="emp">
    <s:property value="id" /><br/>
    <s:property value="name" /><br/>
    <s:property value="role" />
</s:iterator>
```

and

```xml
<s:iterator value="objlistwitharry" >
    <s:property value="id" /><br/>
    <s:property value="name" /><br/>
    <s:property value="role" />
</s:iterator>
```

but none of the above solution is working.

Comment: One question... Who is harry?

Answer (score 3):

With `var`:

```xml
<s:iterator value="objlistwitharry" var="currentListElementThatIsAnArray">
    <s:iterator value="currentListElementThatIsAnArray" var="currentArrayElement">
        <s:property value="id" /><br/>
        <s:property value="name" /><br/>
        <s:property value="role" />
    </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```

or with `top`:

```xml
<s:iterator value="objlistwitharry">
    <s:iterator value="top">
        <s:property value="id" /><br/>
        <s:property value="name" /><br/>
        <s:property value="role" />
    </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```

and IIRC even this works:

```xml
<s:iterator value="objlistwitharry">
    <s:iterator>
        <s:property value="id" /><br/>
        <s:property value="name" /><br/>
        <s:property value="role" />
    </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```

[Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19516627/1654265) on the topic.

P.S: even if it's possible to iterate it, consider the usage of better shaped structures for the future...